# Cleaning Column Data Where Data Has Repeated Itself (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following partially cleaned DataFrame (sample below):

```
Year    Artist                                        Song
2009    Black Eyed Peas                               Boom Boom Pow
1984    U2                                            Bad
1998    Twain, ShaniaShania Twain                     You Belong With Me
2009    Gaga, LadyLady Gaga featuring Colby O'Donis   Just Dance
2008    Winehouse, AmyAmy Winehouse                   Rehab
```

In the column "Artist", some of the data is clean (e.g. 'U2' and 'Black Eyed Peas') but some of it needs to be further cleaned - such as the record for Shania Twain where her name has repeated twice and the Lady Gaga record where her name is stated twice but Colby O'Donis is stated once.  Ideally, I'd like it to look like this:

```
Year    Artist                                        Song
2009    Black Eyed Peas                               Boom Boom Pow
1984    U2                                            Bad
1998    Shania Twain                                  You Belong With Me
2009    Lady Gaga featuring Colby O'Donis             Just Dance
2008    Amy Winehouse                                 Rehab
```

I've been trying to use split, replace etc. - these have helped me get to this stage - but have found it impossible to progress as there is no consistency across the 'Artist' column.

I'd be grateful if anyone could please assist with suggestions.  The df has about 120,000 rows so I need to be able to continue to clean this in Python.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution I came up with, though this assumes that your duplication will always occur when artist name is "lastName, firstNamefirstName lastName" because otherwise, AmyAmy Winehouse may actually be the name of a band and it would be an incorrect replacement

```
def removeDuplicateArtist(stringInput):
    if "," in stringInput:
        names = stringInput.split(" ")
        artist = names[1][int(len(names[1])/2):] + " "
        names.remove(names[0])
        names.remove(names[0])
        for i in names:
            artist += str(i) + " "
        return artist
```

Comment: Updated it to handle "Gaga, LadyLady Gaga featuring Colby O'Donis"

Comment: Hi Alex, appreciate you taking the time to respond.  I've tried your code and get the error:

    "UnboundLocalError: ("local variable 'names' referenced before assignment", u'occurred at index 0')" and it is pointing to the line "for i in names".  Sorry about this formatting, can post up above in my question if this makes it easier.

Comment: I've tried it with multiple fields and still haven't replicated your error. It could be due to a formatting error in my answer. I fixed the indentation so give it another go

Comment: What input did the function fail on? You can add a `print(stringInput)` as the first line of the if-statement if you're unsure

Comment: Hi Alex, sorry for the delay in replying.  Formatting was ok, error was when I was trying to apply it to my data (was an error at my end - created a new iPython workbook and it seemed to be fine).  Thanks for all of your help, I really appreciate it.